# Custom JavaScript to existing Joomla core module

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have developed a custom Joomla template, and I need to add a piece of custom javascript to a Joomla core module (mod_articles_news), without a plugin, if possible (this should be so simple that I don't think I want to use a third party plugin for that). And async, if possible.

I have been searching thoroughly, but haven't found the perfect solution. Either they want me to install a plugin or the solution refers to a custom written module (suggesting to add JS before installation of module) while I am dealing with a core module (Articles Newsflash) that is already installed per definition. (The reason I need to use JS is to make a conditional design change, presently not possible with CSS).

I have been following the steps outlined [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Advanced_topics#Adding_JavaScript), but to no avail. Namely, I added the following code into the module's template folder (mod_articles_news/tmpl/my-template-name.php)

```
<?php
JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/my-template-name/js/myScript.js');
?>
```

(Of course, I have added the myScript.js file into the above location).

When checking it live, nothing happens, the browser is not loading my JavaScript at all (the script itself is tested and it works).

Please help me what I am missing here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your module cached?

Comment: My second question would be: why don't you add this JavaScript file to your templates index.php file?

Comment: @SvenBluege, no, the module is not cached. As for the second question, I thought that this was a cleaner way than adding it directly to my template's index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do customization you should use a Joomla! template for this. A template determines the basic HTML including the necessary CSS/JS for your site. In addition it can contain overrides for modules and components so you can do even more customization without touching any of the original code.

What you want to do sounds like a simple customization. Just add any CSS/JS which is necessary to achieve your task to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<?php
JHTML::script('templates/my-template-name/js/myScript.js');
?>
```

alternatively, is there any reason you can't add it via your custom template, as suggested by [Sven Bluege](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680552/sven-bluege)